# Proving a group is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $pq$, where $p,q$ are primes, $p < q$ and $q≢1$ (mod $p$); how do we prove that $G$ is cyclic ? (I have no idea)

Comment: This is a standard exercise in applying some Sylow theorems, e.g. [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cyclic_Groups_of_Order_pq). Or for a different way [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67129/groups-of-order-pq-without-using-sylow-theorems).

Comment: @T. Bongers: Could you please give some more hints

Comment: @T.Bongers: Ah! thanks.

Comment: Hint: Is there someone who must be normal?

Comment: It would be better and useful for you if you can write your solution in your own words and accept it (assuming you understood the solution with help of given links)..