# Proving $|G|=pq$ and $p>q$ , $q$ does not divide $p-1$ $\implies$ $G$ is cyclic , without using Cauchy's and Sylow's theorems

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Without using Cauchy's or Sylow's theorems , can we give a proof of the result that "If $ p,q$ are primes such that $p>q$ and $q$ does not divide $p-1$ , then any group of order $pq$ is cyclic " ?

Comment: You may see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67129/groups-of-order-pq-without-using-sylow-theorems) where Jack Schimit use only Lagrange theorem