# Without using Cauchy's or Sylow theorems ; can we prove that every group of order $65$ is cyclic?

Tags: finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Without using Cauchy's or Sylow theorems, can we prove that every group of order $65$ is cyclic? Please help, thanks in advance (any technique of group homomorphisms and normal subgroups can be used).

Comment: Yes. In principle you can enumerate all possible multiplication tables ...

Answer (score 3):

Well known theorem that

> groups of order $pq$ (primes, $p<q$) are cyclic except when $p | (q-1)$.

I think this is from looking at the conjugation action of a cyclic $p$ subgroup on the whole group.  Or follow the chain of duplicates...

[Proving $|G|=pq$ and $p>q$ , $q$ does not divide $p-1$ $\implies$ $G$ is cyclic , without using Cauchy's and Sylow's theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910774/proving-g-pq-and-pq-q-does-not-divide-p-1-implies-g-is-cyclic?rq=1)