# If $q$ is not a divisor of $p-1$, then $G$ is cyclic. An open discussion on different proofs.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, semidirect-product

Let $G$ be a group of order $pq$, where $p > q$ are primes.

a) If $q$ is not a divisor of $p-1$, then $G$ is cyclic.

I know the proof using Sylow's theorem but I was wondering if it can be proved without using Sylow's theorem. I always thought that even if such a proof will exist then that will be a proof of Sylow's theorem first without naming it because in I N Herstein this problem is given before discussing Sylow's theorem it propelled my thought again.

Here is my go what I think that everyone would do that **Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ with order $p$ and $K$ be a subgroup of order $q$,**

**It is easy to see that $H$ must be normal in $G$**

**Now can we directly take the action of $K$ on $Aut(H)$ by conjugation without stating anything because this might give you one view point of generating groups. For a student facing the problem of I N Herstein might not know that this is the only way here!!**

So what is your best bet here? Is there any way out? Say counting arguement or so!!

Because if we jot down the question the biggest non-trivial(please forgive me if it would be trivial for you then the rest would trivial as well, that is why..) fact is to prove that $K$ is normal. ***Can anyone prove it without using Sylow's theorem? Or any other interesting way is most welcome.***

**P.S: You can mark it as duplicate as a lot of similar question has been posted but let me justify why this post is different. The answers discussed there, are derived by using Sylow's theorem or Semi-direct product so I tried to have an open discussion on different proofs of the problem. Thanks a lot**

Comment: Have a look at the answers given at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67129/groups-of-order-pq-without-using-sylow-theorems as I think there are a couple that don't use semi-direct products.

Comment: Have you had a look at the link, Shadow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a purely numeric approach:

Let $h$ be a generator of $H$ (so $h^p = e$) and $k$ generate $K$ (so $k^q = e$).  By normality of $H$, we have $k^{-1}hk = h^m$ for some $m$ in [1..p-1].  It is an easy induction from this to see that $k^{-i}hk^i = h^{m^i}$ for all $i$; from this we have specifically that $h^1 = h = k^{-q}hk^q = h^{m^q}$, so necessarily $1 = m^q$ (mod p).  Also, by Fermat's Little Theorem, we have $1 = m^{p-1}$ (mod p).  If $q$ does not divide $p-1$, then necessarily 1 = GCD($q$,$p-1$), so there are integers $r$, $s$ such that $1 = rq + s(p-1)$.  Then $m = m^1 = m^{rq + s(p-1)} = (m^q)^r (m^{p-1})^s$ $= 1^r1^s = 1$ (mod p).  Hence $k^{-1}hk = h$, so $h$ and $k$ commute, and so we have an (inner) direct product of $H$ and $K$ (which we see is cyclic, as $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime).

Answer (score 3):

Consider just the morphism $G \rightarrow Aut(H)$ given by conjugation. Note that its range $R$ must divide both $|G|=qp$ and $|Aut(H)|=p-1$ (because $H$ cyclic, $|H|=p$).

So since $q$ and $p-1$ are coprime, $|R|=1$, ie the morphism is trivial, so the group is abelian and the conclusion follows easily.

Edit: proving that the group is abelian, given that the morphism is trivial, as mentioned in the comment, is not obvious.

Let $C$ be the subgroup of all elements commuting with $K$. $K$ is cyclic so $K \subset C$ so $q||C|$. Since the morphism above is trivial, $H \subset C$ thus $p||C|$ and thus $pq||C|$ ie $C=G$.

Thus the center $Z$ of $G$ contains both $H$ and $K$ so is $G$ (for similar reasons).

Comment: I have a question actually at the last line. The morphism is trivial then how do we say directly that the group is abelian. Will you please expand that?